# Good way to set up user login and manage with 3d party site on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to set up simple user account related logic in Rails.

For now I have only the 3d-party site with API, which returns all user data needed - so Devise looks like a huge overhead. The login scenario is:

```
user -> myApp -> centralApp
```

If the provided info is correct I get an object with data and allow user to perform actions which require authentication.

The question is, how this should be organized? I want to get something like `User.logged_in?` and `User.login!(username, password)`. But not libs nor models could not use session to store data. And without sessions it is hard to imagine how to store per-user info between requests.

The option is to store data and load it from the controller (ApplicationController?) but it looks a bit dirty to have related code spreaded here and there.